# How to access environment variables in client side code during build in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

Related:

- https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/11287
- [how to use environment variable in client and server at the very beginning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850420/how-to-use-environment-variable-in-client-and-server-at-the-very-beginning)

I'm also aware of `METEOR_SETTINGS`.

I have a Meteor app that will be deployed for different clients with different theming/features. I want to use an env variable such as `process.env.CLIENT` and have code like `if(process.env.CLIENT === 'foo')`. During build the env variable should be replaced and dead code elimination will remove/strip the if-block. This already works with `NODE_ENV`.

I don't want to ship code that a certain client does not need and I also don't want to implicitly expose the list of other clients. Both these things would happen if I check `Meteor.settings` at runtime. I need this to happen at compile time. Each client gets a different build.

How do I get environment variables through to the client? How are others solving this? `process.env` on the client currently is:

```json
{"NODE_ENV":"development","TEST_METADATA":"{}"}
```

In other build tools I can either access all env variables on the client or those with a special prefix (for security reasons) like `FOO_`.

Comment: Why using methods to fetch `METEOR_SETTING` isn't an option? You can call the methods in `Meteor.startup` on client side so it runs before anything else.

Comment: If you are making different builds, why not just use a bash script to replace the "variables" with hard-coded values. That is roughly how, e.g., webpack does it, too.

Comment: Meteor settings is exactly built for that where you just assign different `settings.json` for different deployments. With `mup` you can easily manage this, because each deployment has one folder with one mup settings and one settings.json. This is how we deploy multiple instances of the same app to different customers.

Comment: @Jankapunkt I must be missing something about Meteor settings: I need things to be removed at _compile time_, which is what my answer does (and what I'm already doing in non-Meteor projects). I'm aware that I can use Meteor settings for each build to configure things at _runtime_. Could you post an answer how to integrate Meteor settings into the build process?

Comment: It's just a JSON file inside a deployment folder so you can transform it however you want at any stage. `mup` also allows to write hooks for that so no babel, webpack etc. required. Since you will have a different settings file in your deployment folder it will also not modify your development settings file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As usual a night of sleep brought the answer: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables/

```sh
meteor npm install babel-plugin-transform-inline-environment-variables --save-dev
```

Add `.babelrc`

```json
{
  "plugins": [
    ["transform-inline-environment-variables", {
      "include": [
        "CLIENT"
      ]
    }]
  ]
}
```

Now both of these work as expected

```sh
CLIENT=foo meteor run
CLIENT=foo meteor build --directory $OUT
```

(sprinkle in some `m -rf .meteor/local/plugin-cache/` before switching clients in development to properly rebuild)

Original code:

```js
if (process.env.CLIENT === 'foo') {
  console.log('Client is foo');
} else if (process.env.CLIENT === 'bar') {
  console.log('Client is bar');
}
```

Output during development:

```js
if ("foo" === 'foo') {
  console.log('Client is foo');
} else if ("foo" === 'bar') {
  console.log('Client is bar');
}
```

Output in production:

```js
console.log("Client is foo")
```

During development this allows me to easily switch between clients. While working on the same client adding/removing `process.env.CLIENT` works as expected and with hmr etc.

For deployments I'm using [dokku](https://github.com/dokku/dokku). That means once I've configured the environments (`dokku config:set app CLIENT=foo`) I can do:

```
git push client_foo main
git push client_bar main
```

to deploy both clients from the same branch without worrying that things get messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Creating multiple, distinct builds is not something Meteor support natively. I think it's also fairly unusual.

However, since it is separate processes, you can just build support for it yourself using a bash script similar to this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

FOO_VALUE=$1
echo "Using variable value $FOO_VALUE";

for file in $(find imports/ui/); do
  echo "Replacing special variables in $file"
  sed -i "s/FOO_CLIENT/$FOO_VALUE/g" $file;
done

DIR="build_$FOO_VALUE/"
mkdir -p $DIR
meteor build -d $DIR
```

Comment: Thanks! Interesting idea, but I think this answer is missing a critical part: how will this work during development?

Comment: You tell me. How do you do this currently during development and how do you want it to be? You are creating separate builds, do you also run separate meteor instances in development? Or would you like to keep just one instance in development? All the above are possible with the right use of syntax for the magic variables.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in @ChristianFritz's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69916818/5108796), your use case does not seem to be directly supported by Meteor build system.

As you found out, a current solution could be to rely on Meteor Settings, but you would still ship code for all cases (clients/customers) in your bundle.

If I were to use a workaround, I would gather all customer-specific code in separate folders, and swap with a symlink. That way, the rest of your application would import those bits with a constant path. Obviously, make sure to update the symlink target before every customer-specific build.

But such use case would also imply a customer-specific server bundle. This might be fine for you, if you plan to have 1 server per customer, as you seem to imply by "*Each client gets a different build.*"

Comment: Thanks! Interesting idea, but symlinks offer room for human error and require labor. I also want to have if/else in the same file, that's much easier for what I'm doing.

Comment: "_symlinks offer room for human error and require labor_": there is really no need to handle them manually; npm scripts / your preferred automation tool is the way to go.